# How to join those tables to get correct result

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to figure out this query for a few hours now without success.

I have 3 tables:
 - jstyle_category
 - style
 - subsite_style_alias

the tables have this schema:

- jstyle_category:

  - style_id
  - category_id
  - subsite_id (INT)
  - sort_order
  - active (ENUM: y,n)
- style

  - id
  - subsite_id (STRING, comma separated)
  - active (ENUM: y,n)
  - currently_available_for_sale (ENUM: y,n)
  - style_type_id
  - date_active (DATETIME)
- subsite_style_alias

  - style_id
  - pos
  - show
  - subsite_logo_group_id
  - subsite_id (INT)

The records are something like

- jstyle_category

  - 1234, 27, 572, 0, y
  - 8800, 27, 572, 1, y
  - 8800, 23, 953, 0, y
  - 8500, 23, 572, 0, y
- style

  - 1234, 572, y, y, 99, 0000-00-00
  - 8800, 123, y, y, 99, 0000-00-00
  - 8500, 572, y, y, 99, 0000-00-00
- subsite_style_alias

  - 8800, 0, y, 2589, 572
  - 8800, 1, y, 3475, 572
  - 8800, 1, y, 9554, 368

what I need a subset that contains all the items in jstyle_category where category_id = 27 with the data from subsite_style_alias if present (and this part I have done it with the following query).  My Real problem is that currently I am getting something like:

- 27, 0, 1234, NULL, NULL
- 27, 0, 8800, 0, 2589
- 27, 1, 8800, 1, 3475

What I need is the 8800 where there is no corresponding subsite_style_alias, so the final result will be

- 27, 0, 1234, NULL, NULL
- 27, 1, 8800, NULL, NULL
- 27, 0, 8800, 0, 2589
- 27, 1, 8800, 1, 3475

I know I am close to the answer, I just can't figure it out.

I am also trying to avoid Unions if possible and rather use joins of the same tables

```
SELECT  jstyle_category.category_id category_id,
    jstyle_category.sort_order category_pos,
    style.id style_id,
    subsite_style_alias.pos pos,
    subsite_style_alias.subsite_logo_group_id
FROM  `jstyle_category` 
    LEFT JOIN style ON style.id = jstyle_category.style_id
    LEFT JOIN subsite_style_alias ON style.id = subsite_style_alias.style_id AND subsite_style_alias.subsite_id = 572
WHERE 
(

    (
        style.subsite_id = ""  OR 
        FIND_IN_SET("0",style.subsite_id) OR 
        FIND_IN_SET("572",style.subsite_id)
    ) AND 

    (
        subsite_style_alias.`active` = "y"  OR 
        subsite_style_alias.`active` IS NULL 
    ) AND 
    style.active = "y"  AND 
    style.currently_available_for_sale = "y"  AND 
    style.style_type_id NOT IN (7,10,11)  AND 
    jstyle_category.category_id = 27  AND 
    jstyle_category.subsite_id IN (0,572)  AND 
    jstyle_category.active = "y"  AND 

    (
        style.date_active IS NULL  OR 
        style.date_active <= "2012-02-24 18:00:00" 
    )
)
GROUP BY subsite_style_alias.subsite_logo_group_id,
    style.id
ORDER BY category_pos, subsite_style_alias.pos IS NULL,
    subsite_style_alias.pos,
    style.id
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding a new table formed by just NULL and then adding extra logic in the WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Change `LEFT JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

See [this reference on outer joins in MySQL](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/outer-join-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a `LEFT JOIN` with a table and what I call a `NULL` table:

```
FROM mytab
   LEFT JOIN (
      (SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table) UNION (SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL)
   ) tmp_table ON mybab.field = tmp_table.field1
```

I didn't want to use `UNIONS`, but this is the most efficient way that I was able to find out when I have to do an `UNION` with multiple tables